# How to change line height of wrapped div text without increasing margin?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add line-height to my text inside my div so that when the text wraps in mobile view, it can be consistent with my margins. Specifically, the copyright div text.

```
<div class='footer-section'>Company logo</div>
<div class="footer-section copyright">Copyright &copy; {{ year }}. All Rights Reserved.</div>
<div class='footer-section'>Bottom Element</div>
```

Here is an image with the text wrapped. The orange box is a 15px margin. I am trying to space out the "Copyright 2020. All Rights" line from the "Reserved." line

[image: Here is an image with the text wrapped. The orange box is a 15px margin]

When I add line-height to the div, there is space added to below and above the element, creating extra space. Setting line-height to 200%, creates extra space along the margin, which you can see under the Company logo text, between the orange box and the Copyright text

[image: The orange block is a 15px margin, setting line-height to 200%, creates extra space along the margin]

I have searched all over for a way to increase the line-height between wrapped text without adding extra margin to the element. I played with the display property, line-height, and vertical-align, but can't seem to get the desired result. I want there to be spacing between the wrapped text but not extra spacing below the 15px margin (orange box) and the text

Here are some of the styles

```
.footer-section + .footer-section {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.footer-section.copyright {
    line-height: 200%;
}
```

If it is still unclear, here is a diagram:
The green arrow is what I want to achieve, the spacing between the Copyright text, which is one line that is wrapped around because this is how the mobile view will appear for a user. The red arrows are the extra space added from setting the line-height attribute, which I do not want

[image: Diagram with arrows]

Comment: Can you please provide a visual a what you expect?

Comment: place this tag at the begining of your body tag : `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` this will wrap your text and make it resposive as well, not only text, it will make the whole webpage responsive

Comment: @johannchopin In the second image, you can see that the orange box has a space below it that the first image does not. I am trying to increase the line height of the wrapped text without adding that extra margin below the orange box between the Copyright text

Comment: Could you include the styles for `footer-section` and `copyright`. This might make answering the question easier.

Comment: https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/BaKRxNd is this what you're doing?

Otherwise, I would strongly ask you to provide the entire <style> applied to both the classes in question before we can help you.

Comment: I included the styles in the question. @NFL yes that is essentially what I'm doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.footer-section:not(.footer-section.copyright ) {
    margin-top: 15px;
    line-height: 100%;
}

.footer-section.copyright {
    line-height: 200%;
}
```

If I'm getting the question right, you want the line-height property to be applied to only the copyright text, in which case this might do the trick. Also codepen: https://codepen.io/flyingDonut/pen/BaKRxNd

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky for what you asking because it isn't completely clear what you want. However;

If you adding line-height to your rows what it does is simple, it is adding basically margins to the top and bottom part of that line of text and will centered the text vertically of the next row.

What I think you want is this:

```
.footer-section.copyright {padding-top: 1rem;} // 1 rem is by default 16px
```

Comment: Hey, sorry it wasn't clear, I tried to explain a bit better in the post. I want to add space between lines of wrapped text, so that the text can be spaced out similarly to how the margins are adding spacing between the divs. Adding the line-height property achieves this, but also adds the undesired space between the margin and the text, which is the area below the orange box you can see in the second image

Comment: If you just delete the line-height it should be fixed like my example and change the rem unit by place what you prefer.